# Mistake in the OpenGL tutorial?

Tags: c++

As I was learning OpenGL I came upon this tutorial:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_02

It contains this piece of code:

```
struct point {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat s;
    GLfloat t;
  } coords[6 * strlen(text)];
```

The declared array size is not a constant expression so it doesn't compile. Is this a mistake in the tutorial or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it a C library/tutorial? Because C supports VLA since – C11(? – think though; big mistake in my eyes, by the way…).

Comment: Yes and No. Since C99, Variable-Length-Arrays are allowed (and optional since C11). Make sure you compile with the correct standard. If you use Windows, VLAs are not supported. Since MSVC does not fully support the C Standards

Comment: OK, stand corrected, C99 – and since C11 *optional* feature according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). In any case I'd avoid to remain fully portable (considering non-supporting compilers and for C++ compatibility).

Comment: 1) Get rid of the `C` "struct", where it looks like this: `struct foo { stuff; } coords[num];`, since it looks odd to a C++ programmer anyway, and just define a `struct`, i.e. `struct foo { stuff; };`.  2) Use `std::vector` to create "arrays" of these structs, i.e. `std::vector<foo> coords(num);`.  3) Adjust the sample code to use `std::vector`.  It should work, given that `std::vector` stores its elements contiguously, exactly like an array anyway.

Comment: Side note: Even in C++ some compilers support VLA as a language *extension* – should be avoided even more than in C as you never know when code breaks at another compiler. GCC and clang allow switching off these extensions by using `-std=c++<version>` (recommended).

Comment: Also, as to `std::vector`, use the `data()` member function to get a pointer to the underlying array, and `size()` to get the number of elements.  Use these to adjust the samples you see on the wiki page.

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right, this example was probably meant to be C, I assumed it was c++ because the tutorial file had a .cpp extension (https://gitlab.com/wikibooks-opengl/modern-tutorials/-/blob/master/text02_atlas/text.cpp)

Comment: @JGondek The compiler usually deduces the language to compile in from the file ending; `.cpp` indeed indicates C++. While not legal in standard C++ the author of the example might be using a compiler supporting VLA-extension, like e.g. both GCC and clang, and having these enabled. GCC and clang have them enabled by default, even worse, they remain enabled with `-std=c++20` and need to be explicitly turned off via `-Werror=vla` (recommend to use this as default setting for any project of yours), see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xTWs4a8GK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can port this fragment to standard C++ as follows:

```
void render_text(const char *text, float x, float y, float sx, float sy) {
  struct point {
    GLfloat x,y,s,t;
  };
  std::vector<point> coords;
  coords.reserve(strlen(text) * 6);
 
  for(const char *p = text; *p; p++) { 
    float x2 =  x + c[*p].bl * sx;
    float y2 = -y - c[*p].bt * sy;
    float w = c[*p].bw * sx;
    float h = c[*p].bh * sy;

    /* Advance the cursor to the start of the next character */
    x += c[*p].ax * sx;
    y += c[*p].ay * sy;

    /* Skip glyphs that have no pixels */
    if(!w || !h)
      continue;

    coords.emplace_back(x2,     -y2,     c[*p].tx,                          0);
    coords.emplace_back(x2 + w, -y2,     c[*p].tx + c[*p].bw / atlas_width, 0);
    coords.emplace_back(x2,     -y2 - h, c[*p].tx,                          c[*p].bh / atlas_height); //remember: each glyph occupies a different amount of vertical space
    coords.emplace_back(x2 + w, -y2,     c[*p].tx + c[*p].bw / atlas_width, 0);
    coords.emplace_back(x2,     -y2 - h, c[*p].tx,                          c[*p].bh / atlas_height);
    coords.emplace_back(x2 + w, -y2 - h, c[*p].tx + c[*p].bw / atlas_width, c[*p].bh / atlas_height);
  }

  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, coords.size() * sizeof(struct point), coords.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, n);
}
```

The `emplace_back` calls construct a `point` object at the end of the vector and bump its size pointer by one. At the end of the function the memory is freed as the vector is destructed.

Answer (score 0):

@Aconcagua You're right, this example was probably meant to be written in C, I assumed it was C++ because the tutorial file had a .cpp extension (https://gitlab.com/wikibooks-opengl/modern-tutorials/-/blob/master/text02_atlas/text.cpp).

I changed the file's extension to .c, however the headers included are C++ (`<cstdio>, <cstdlib>` etc) and would have needed to be adjusted as well. I've decided to rewrite the code to standard c++ instead.

Comment: See comments to question: Some C++ compilers support VLA as *non-standard* language extension, so still might be C++ and example author using such a compiler; code is not really C++ idiomatic, though.